# Cerr Not Working

Tags: c++

I wrote a function that takes two numbers from command line and multiples it, and if the argc is not 3 it is supposed to output a cerr line; however it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int product;
 int first_num = atoi(argv[1]);
 int second_num = atoi(argv[2]);
 product = first_num * second_num;
 if(argc != 3)
 {
    cerr << "Usage: ./multiply first_num second_num" << endl;
    exit(1);
 }
 else
 {
    cout << product << endl;
 }
}
```

Instead of the `cerr` printing, a zsh: segmentation fault ./multiply comes out.

Comment: indexing starts at 0

Comment: @marsh: `argv[0]` is the program name.

Comment: You need to move your if statement that checks argc to before you call atoi.

Comment: @jwodder Ah! Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: So do I put int first_num and int second_num inside the if function?

Comment: argv[0] is the program name and argv[1] and argv[2] are the number inputs.

Comment: @toth, you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: argv[0] is still (possibly) the programm name. (It could be something different, that depends on what the OS wants.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass in any arguments to your program, `argv[1]` is a null pointer and `argv[2]` doesn't exist, you're not allowed to access that index. So you don't want to try to pass that to atoi(). Check first, then look at what's at `argv[1]`/`argv[2]` only if you're sure they actually exists.

```
 if(argc != 3)
 {
    cerr << "Usage: ./multiply first_num second_num" << endl;
    exit(1);
 }
 else
 {
    int product;
    int first_num = atoi(argv[1]);
    int second_num = atoi(argv[2]);
    product = first_num * second_num;
    cout << product << endl;
 }
```

Comment: I still don't completely get why I have to put all the int definitions inside of the else. Isn't it still accessing the same variable?

Comment: Yes, but it's only accessing them if they are valid.

Comment: @Ken You could put `int product;` outside. But if you put `int second_num = atoi(argv[2]);` outside, you will be accessing `argv[2]` before you check that it actually is valid. If argc was e.g. 1, then surely you shouldn't try to index `argv[2]`. `argc` tells you how many items in `argv` are present. `argv` starts at 0, so if `argc` is 1, then `argv[0]` is the only element present. `argv[argc + 1]` is technically also present but it is specified to always be a NULL pointer (and you can't pass a NULL pointer to atoi().

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!